# Can't download a file, error 500

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to download a zipped file from Amazon Datafeed url and then decompress it.

This is my code:

```
    open('public/files/amazon_ce.xml', 'w') do |local_file|
      open('https://assoc-datafeeds-eu.amazon.com/datafeed/it_amazon_ce.xml.gz', :http_basic_authentication=>[USERNAME, PASSWORD]) do |remote_file|
        local_file.write(Zlib::GzipReader.new(remote_file).read)
      end
    end
```

If I try with another file everything is ok, but not with this Amazon file: the error is:

```
OpenURI::HTTPError: 500 Internal Server Error
```

I logged the request when I download the same file using the browser...

```
GET /datafeed/getFeed?filename=it_amazon_ce.xml.gz HTTP/1.1
Host: assoc-datafeeds-eu.amazon.com:443
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: xxxxx
Referer: https://assoc-datafeeds-eu.amazon.com/datafeed/listFeeds?format=text/html
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 30 Sep 2015 21:24:22 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC
Location: http://prod-deamazon.outputs.datafeeds.s3.amazonaws.com/it_amazon_dvd.xml.gz?Signature=xxxx&AWSAccessKeyId=xxxx&Expires=xxxx
Pragma: No-cache
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Any idea?

Comment: If you can access it from a browser and not from code I'd suspect that they're sniffing the user-agent information and crashing on their end. Try setting your code's user-agent to that of your browser and see what happens. Alternately, they could be looking for the cookie so you'll need to figure out how to cache/capture that and return it.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is already authenticated and has a cookie which allows you to download the file.

You need to make sure that your Rails app has proper credentials to download the file (I can't in my browser, it asks for username/password)